# Not scaling and/or rotating when exporting map using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, export, arcgis-engine, jpg

I am writing a console application using ArcGIS (engine or desktop). I'm trying to rotate and scale a map based on a polygon, and I'm not having any luck at all. With some tinkering, I can usually do one or the other but not both.

Anybody have any suggestions? I feel as though I've tried every variation in terms of rotating the map and adjusting the scale either using the Imap interface, or the IActiveView interface.

```
    Private Sub Zoom2AndExportJpgs(mapDocument As IMapDocument, imagePath As String)
    'Get the relevant strip maps for the route
    Dim map As IMap = mapDocument.Map(0) '(assumed that there is only one map in the mxd)
    Dim pageLayout As IPageLayout = mapDocument.PageLayout
    Dim pageAV As IActiveView = pageLayout
    Dim mapAV As IActiveView = map
    Try
        'get a list of strip map objects... EF object containing a list of the 4 corners of a polygon
        Dim stripmaps As List(Of MRLAStripMapExtent) = getStripMaps()
        Dim filename As String = ""

        'get all the associated stripmaps for the route  for each scale
        If Not stripmaps Is Nothing Then
            For i = 0 To stripmaps.Count - 1
                Dim pgon As IPolygon = geometryHelper.CreatePGON(stripmaps(i).RectLowerLeftX, stripmaps(i).RectLowerLeftY, _
                                                                                             stripmaps(i).RectLowerRightX, stripmaps(i).RectLowerRightY, _
                                                                                             stripmaps(i).RectUpperLeftX, stripmaps(i).RectUpperLeftY, _
                                                                                            stripmaps(i).RectUpperRightX, stripmaps(i).RectUpperRightY)
                filename = imagePath & stripmaps(i).ZoomScale & stripmaps(i).PageNumber & ".jpg"
                CreateJpgFile(filename, mapAV, pageAV, pgon, stripmaps(i).ANGLE, stripmaps(i).ZoomScale)

            Next i
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        publishError.PublishError(publishError.ErrorSeverity.majorStopRouteProcessing, ex)
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub CreateJpgFile(ByVal sFilename As String, ByVal pAV As ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IActiveView, _
                          ByVal pPageActiveView As ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IActiveView, _
                          ByVal pgon As IPolygon,
                          rotationAngle As Double, _
                          mapScale As Double)

    Dim pExport As ESRI.ArcGIS.Output.IExport
    pExport = New ESRI.ArcGIS.Output.ExportJPEG

    pAV.Extent = pgon.Envelope
    pAV.ScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.ScaleRatio = mapScale
    pAV.ScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.Rotation = rotationAngle '0
    pAV.Refresh()

    'Export Image....
    pExport.ExportFileName = sFilename
    pExport.Resolution = 96
    Dim exportRECT As ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.tagRECT
    exportRECT = pPageActiveView.ExportFrame
    Dim pPixelBoundsEnv As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IEnvelope
    pPixelBoundsEnv = New ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.Envelope
    pPixelBoundsEnv.PutCoords(exportRECT.left, exportRECT.bottom, exportRECT.right, exportRECT.top)
    pExport.PixelBounds = pPixelBoundsEnv
    Dim hDC As Integer
    hDC = pExport.StartExporting
    pPageActiveView.Output(hDC, pExport.Resolution, exportRECT, Nothing, Nothing)

    'Finish writing the export file and cleanup any intermediate files.
    pExport.FinishExporting()
    pExport.Cleanup()
End Sub
```

Comment: Found the answer here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9943/mapscale-not-being-persisted-properly-in-mxd-when-programmatically-changed-outsi .

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually doing something similar.  What tinkering did you do?  I made an envelope and expanded the envelope based on a ratio of the desired scale and the templateMap's scale.

```
mapEnvelope.Expand(scale / templateMap.MapScale, scale / templateMap.MapScale, true);
((IActiveView)templateMap).Extent = mapEnvelope;
```

It loses accuracy though.

Comment: Did this solve the problem or is it another manifestation of the same problem?

Comment: This solved the problem: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9943/mapscale-not-being-persisted-properly-in-mxd-when-programmatically-changed-outsi

Answer (score 1):

You already has the procedure to rotate, it is quite easy...then to scale the map you can use something like this:

```
var p = this.CurrentContentView;
        if (p != null)
        {
            var currentExtent = new Envelope();
            var newExtent = new Envelope();
            var newPoly = new Polygon();
            newExtent = this.Map.get_Layer(0).AreaOfInterest as Envelope;
            if (this.Map.Rotation != 0)
            {
                newExtent = null;
                currentExtent = this.Map.get_Layer(0).AreaOfInterest as Envelope;

                newPoly.AddPoint(new Point()
                                     {
                                         X = currentExtent.XMin,
                                         Y = currentExtent.YMin
                                     });
                newPoly.AddPoint(new Point()
                                     {
                                         X = currentExtent.XMax,
                                         Y = currentExtent.YMax
                                     });
                IPoint center = (currentExtent as IArea).Centroid;
                ITransform2D trans = newPoly as ITransform2D;
                trans.Rotate(center, (p.MapControl.Rotation * (Math.PI / 180)));
                newExtent = ((IGeometry)newPoly).Envelope as Envelope;
            }

            newExtent.Expand(1.1, 1.1, true);
            p.MapControl.ActiveView.Extent = newExtent as IEnvelope;
            p.MapControl.Refresh();
        }
```

Maybe check the objects before copy and paste...but in essence it will work....by the way...the rotation of the polygon is counterclockwise.